# How can I customize the deployment bucket name for Google Cloud via the Serverless Framework?

Tags: google-cloud-functions, serverless-framework

Is there a way to use a predefined bucket using `serverless` and `gcp`?

I tried using:

```
deploymentBucket:
    name: build-artifacts-kkesley
```

...but it ignores it and create it's own bucket.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

No.

What you've posted is how you would customise it with AWS, but the Google provider functionality is actually provided via a plugin and its process is not consistent with the core repository.

The deployment bucket variable that gets set upon deployment to Google is actually `deploymentBucketName` (not `deploymentBucket.name` like AWS) and it only reuses buckets from its own naming convention.

You can dig into the code [here](https://github.com/serverless/serverless-google-cloudfunctions/blob/master/shared/setDeploymentBucketName.js).